# Jquery ui rotatable get rotate degree when it stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var params = {
        // Callback fired on rotation start.
        start: function(event, ui) {
        },
        // Callback fired during rotation.
        rotate: function(event, ui) {
        },
        // Callback fired on rotation end.
        stop: function(event, ui) {

        //Need to get rotate degree

        },
};
$('#target').rotatable(params);
```

I have a page use jquery-ui-rotatable plugin

My question is how can I get user's rotate degree when it stop?

(ex. if user rotate the div 30 degree, alert(30);)

https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the page you've linked:

> The start, rotate and stop callbacks provide the following in the ui argument of the callback:
>
> ...
>
> - angle: An object containing information about the rotation angle, with the following keys:
>
>   ...
>
>   - stop: The angle at the end of the rotation.

Thus, you can read the final angle (in radians) from `ui.angle.stop` inside the `stop` callback:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.angle.stop);
},
```

To convert the value to degrees, you can simply do `ui.angle.stop / Math.PI * 180`.